# Camel route message to replyTo and error queue

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I'm newbie with camel.
I try to achieve the following behavior.
I have message with filled JMSReplyTo header.
When any exception is thrown, i catch, format and log it.
Then i want to send it to errors queue and send back to client by JMSReplyTo.
This my route config.

```
onException(Exception.class)
        .transform().simple("Message:\n${body}\nHeaders:\n${headers}\nException:\n${exception.stacktrace}")
        .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, "errors","${body}")
        .to("activemq:queue:GENERAL.ERRORS")
        .end();
    from("activemq:queue:changeProfitCenter.input")
        .choice()
            .when(header("JMSType").isEqualTo("xml"))
                .to("direct:xmlChangeProfitCenter")
            .when(header("JMSType").isEqualTo("json"))
                .to("direct:jsonChangeProfitCenter")
            .otherwise()
                .transform(simple("Incorrect message type JMSType = '${header.JMSType}'"))
        .end()
    .end();


    from("direct:jsonChangeProfitCenter")
        .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, Request.class)
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "unmarshal json : ${body}")
        .bean(testService, "changeProfitCenter")
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "service response : ${body}")
        .end();

    from("direct:xmlChangeProfitCenter")
        .unmarshal().jaxb("model")
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "unmarshal xml : ${body}")
        .bean(testService, "changeProfitCenter")
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "service response : ${body}")
        .end();
}
```

When i send incorrect message and catch ParseException, i see such behavior. Message transformed, logged, sended to GENERAL.ERRORS, after 20 seconds message disapeared from queue and moved to DLQ and i can see this stacktrace in my application.

```
12:10:51.637 [Camel (camel-1) thread #6 - JmsReplyManagerOnTimeout[GENERAL.ERRORS]] WARN  o.a.c.c.j.r.TemporaryQueueReplyManager - Timeout occurred after 20000 millis waiting for reply message with correlationID [Camel-ID-1521796109842-0-4] on destination temp-queue://ID:1521796109515-1:1:1. Setting ExchangeTimedOutException on (MessageId: ID:38611-1521795301468-8:2:1:1:2 on ExchangeId: ID-1521796109842-0-3) and continue routing.
12:10:51.683 [Camel (camel-1) thread #6 - JmsReplyManagerOnTimeout[GENERAL.ERRORS]] ERROR o.a.c.p.FatalFallbackErrorHandler - Exception occurred while trying to handle previously thrown exception on exchangeId: ID-1521796109842-0-3 using: [Pipeline[[Channel[Transform(Simple: Message:
${body}
Headers:
${headers}
Exception:
${exception.stacktrace})], Channel[Log(errors)[body]], Channel[sendTo(activemq://queue:GENERAL.ERRORS)]]]]. The previous and the new exception will be logged in the following.
12:10:51.683 [Camel (camel-1) thread #6 - JmsReplyManagerOnTimeout[GENERAL.ERRORS]] ERROR o.a.c.p.FatalFallbackErrorHandler - \--> Previous exception on exchangeId: ID-1521796109842-0-3
java.io.IOException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
12:10:51.698 [Camel (camel-1) thread #6 - JmsReplyManagerOnTimeout[GENERAL.ERRORS]] ERROR o.a.c.p.FatalFallbackErrorHandler - \--> New exception on exchangeId: ID-1521796109842-0-3
org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not received within: 20000 millis due reply message with correlationID: Camel-ID--1521796109842-0-4 not received on destination: temp-queue://ID:54045-1521796109515-1:1:1. Exchange[ID-1521796109842-0-3]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.ReplyManagerSupport.processReply(ReplyManagerSupport.java:170)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.TemporaryQueueReplyHandler.onTimeout(TemporaryQueueReplyHandler.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.CorrelationTimeoutMap$1.run(CorrelationTimeoutMap.java:60)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:514)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
12:10:51.698 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - JmsConsumer[changeProfitCenter.input]] WARN  o.a.c.c.jms.EndpointMessageListener - Execution of JMS message listener failed. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException - org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not received within: 20000 millis due reply message with correlationID: Camel-ID-1521796109842-0-4 not received on destination: temp-queue://ID:54045-1521796109515-1:1:1. Exchange[ID-1521796109842-0-3]]
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not received within: 20000 millis due reply message with correlationID: Camel-ID-1521796109842-0-4 not received on destination: temp-queue://ID:54045-1521796109515-1:1:1. Exchange[ID-1521796109842-0-3]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1831)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener$EndpointMessageListenerAsyncCallback.done(EndpointMessageListener.java:195)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:116)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:719)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:679)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:649)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:317)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:255)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1166)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1158)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1055)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not received within: 20000 millis due reply message with correlationID: Camel-ID-1521796109842-0-4 not received on destination: temp-queue://ID:54045-1521796109515-1:1:1. Exchange[ID-1521796109842-0-3]
```

I have some questions.
1) Why message not processed to client. If i delete `.to("activemq:queue:GENERAL.ERRORS")`, it will deliver to client. But i want send it to client and ERRORS queue.
2)Why i have ExchangeTimedOutException when JMSExpiration=0.

Can someone help me to  provide sending exception to reply to and errors queues?
My final goal will to send message in error queue  with one formatting and reply to queue with defferent formatting.
I know about multicast but its provide sending same message to multiple queues. thats not what i desire

Answer (score 0):

You can create an errorHandler and send it to your queue, once I did it with RabbitMQ, is something like this:

```
/**
     * Dead Letter Channel, it will try delivery the message three times each 60 seconds
     */
    errorHandler(
            deadLetterChannel("rabbitmq:{{RABBITMQ_ADDRESS}}/{{RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE}}?routingKey={{RABBITMQ_QUEUE_DLQ_ROUTING_KEY}}&username={{RABBITMQ_USERNAME}}&password={{RABBITMQ_PSWD}}&autoDelete=false&queue={{RABBITMQ_QUEUE_DLQ}}")
                    .logExhaustedMessageHistory(true)
                    .maximumRedeliveries(3)
                    .redeliveryDelay(60000)
                    .onPrepareFailure(new FailExecution())
                    .onRedelivery(new RetryExecution()));
from("direct:youtRoute").to("log:foo");
```

If it helps you, here is my project with a queue.

https://github.com/vtripeno/integration_camel_apis